# In War Metal Tyrant, where can I actually watch my saved replays?

Tags: war-metal-tyrant

There's a button with a camera icon that lets me save a replay of a battle once it's over. The tooltip even says, "Save your replay to show off to your friends!" However, I don't see a way to actually *play back* those saved replays (let alone share them with others). I have looked everywhere and searched the War Metal Tyrant wikia, to no avail.

Comment: The in game chat claims that it only works for Facebook; I assume you are using Kongregate?

Comment: @MrHen: Yes. I wasn't able to create a [war-metal-tyrant] tag due to lacking rep, and had to go with just [war-metal] instead. But I do mean the Tyrant version, on Kongregate.

Comment: Strange... if it works only on Facebook, stupid that they have that link there! And hai.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I can actually answer this now. Players in the game chat claim that it only works for Facebook. Having checked all screens and buttons, I have not found a way to view replays or share them.